# MPU6050 IMU quaternion conversion

Tags: arduino

I have a dilemma for a control system, and due to my poor maths ability am unable to resolve it despite days of googling -

I am using an Arduino with an MPU6050 to get Yaw, Pitch, and Roll which is converted from a quaternion (to prevent gimbal lock)

This issue i have is due to space i am unable to mount the gyroscope flat with x facing forwards, z facing up/down and y facing left. Instead, i can only mount the gyroscope with x facing down, y facing forwards and z facing right / left.    EG Axis ( Roll , Pitch , Yaw ) have become (Yaw,Roll,Pitch). I am trying to convert the quaternion to reflect this change, but have no idea how. I have tried adding a quaternion to it, but no success. Anyone got any ideas how best to use an IMU mounted this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong here but since you're rotating the orientation vector(yaw, pitch, roll) by a constant rotation you don't need to worry about gimbal lock. You can simply multiply your orientation vector by the corresponding pre-calculated rotation matrix.

Comment: Done the trick, i had previously tried this (incorrectly), and dismissed it as the wrong method. I put more time into it after your answer and it is working excellent now. Thanks very much.

Comment: As far as implementation, it is easiest to express the overall rotation of system coordinates by a quaternion, and then just multiply the quaternions to get your result.